# How to check whether word within array is included in string, without regex?

Tags: javascript, string, substring, words

I’m trying to figure out why my code is not giving the right output.

My `input` shouldn’t be contained within the `array` elements.

I found an easy way to solve it with regex, so I am not using regex for that one.

Please, break down my code, and tell me what is the problem with the code.

```js
function checkInput(input, words) {
  var arr = input.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  var i, j;
  var matches = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
      if (arr[i] != words[j]) {
        matches++;
      }
    }
  }
  if (matches > 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

console.log(checkInput("Move an array element from one array", ["from"])); // should be false
console.log(checkInput("Move an array element from one array", ["elem"])); // should be true
```

Comment: So you mean, the function should return `true` iff no element of your `words` array is a word in your `input` string, right?

Comment: @Xufox, thats right.

Answer (score 1):

`if (arr[i] != words[j])` will be `true` at some point or another most of the time.

You want to check the opposite and return the opposite logic, so:

```
if(arr[i] == words[j]) {
  matches++;
}
```

and

```
if (matches > 0) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

But a simpler way would be:

```
function checkInput(input, words){
  let lowerCaseInput = input.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  return words.find(word => lowerCaseInput.includes(word)) === undefined;
}
```

[`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) will return `undefined` iff no element is found that satisfies a specific rule provided by the callback function, `word => lowerCaseInput.includes(word)` in this case. So we check whether its return value is `undefined` which will tell us whether a *word* has been matched in `input`.

Note that *your* function unnecessarily checks for the *entire* `words` array even though it only matters whether *one* word matches.

Also, the words in `words` are case-sensitive! If you don’t want that, replace `.includes(word)` by `.includes(word.toLowerCase())`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `matches > 0`, you think it will return `true` only when no matches is found. But what happens is that when you have input `ab aa cc` and word `aa`

- first iteration `matches` = 1
- second iteration `matches` = 1
- third iteration `matches` = 2

So matches will contain how many times `word` is different from items of `input`. So as result, it will always return `true` as long as `input` is more than two words long, for at least one word of `input` will be different from `word`. You can rather consider increasing the value of `matches` if `word` is found instead.

```js
function checkInput(input, words) {
    var arr = input.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    var i, j;
    var matches = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] === words[j]) {
                matches++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (matches === 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

console.log(checkInput("Move an array element from one array", ["from"])); 
console.log(checkInput("Move an array element from one array", ["elem"]));
```

Comment: @Xufox, I was editing the post when you downvoted me. Even if the code itself was not an explanation, I don't think that my answer was wrong to the point of being downvoted as long as my code solves the issue.

Comment: Okay, I understand @Xufox. But you were to quick to downvote the answer. For I was editing it.

Comment: I mean given the sentence `Move an array element from one array`. As long as, the input is more than two words longs, it will always return true.